# How do you incrementally add lexeme/s to an existing Django SearchVectorField document value through the ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search

You can add to an existing Postgresql `tsvector` value using `||`, for example:

```sql
UPDATE acme_table 
SET my_tsvector = my_tsvector || 
        to_tsvector('english', 'some new words to add to existing ones') 
WHERE id = 1234;
```

Is there any way to access this functionality via the Django ORM? I.e. incrementally add to an existing `SearchVectorField` value rather than reconstruct from scratch?

The issue I'm having is the `SearchVectorField` property returns the `tsvector` as a string. So when I use the `||` operator as `+`, eg:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

instance.my_tsvector_prop += SearchVector(
    ["new", "fields"], 
    weight="A", 
    config='english'
)
```

I get the error:

`TypeError: SearchVector can only be combined with other SearchVector instances, got str.`

Because:

```py
type(instance.my_tsvector_prop) == str
```

A fix to this open [Django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30637) whereby a `SearchVectorField` property returns a `SearchVector` instance would probably enable this, if possible. (Although less efficient than combining in the database. In our case the update will run asynchronously so performance is not too important.)

```py
MyModel.objects
    .filter(pk=1234)
    .update(my_tsvector_prop=
        F("my_tsvector_prop") + 
        SearchVector(
            ["new_field_name"], 
            weight="A", 
            config='english')
        )
    )
```

Returns:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

Another solution would be to run a raw SQL `UPDATE`, although I'd rather do it through the Django ORM if possible as our `tsvector` fields often reference values many joins away, so it'd be nice to find a sustainable solution.